# Lambda function for multiplying each element of list with random number between 1 and 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, functional-programming

I'm stuck on this question since I am fairly new to functional programming in python. Any help would be appreciated!

Note: I understand using map is simpler since we can use an iterable but I need some way of accomplishing this using lambda function only.

```
Given the following list, ages of 25 people:
ages = [79, 91, 25, 22, 95, 69, 47, 87, 87, 2, 13, 94, 50, 73, 29, 87, 81, 51, 32, 69, 10, 91, 45, 7,
51]
Q: Make a new list in which you multiply each age with a random number between 1 to 10
(Generate a random number for each age and multiply them together). Only use Lambda
Function for the multiplication. (You can use random generator provided by in python to
generate the random numbers)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import random

inconsistent = []
ages = [79, 91, 25, 22, 95, 69, 47, 87, 87, 2, 13, 94, 50, 73, 29, 87, 81, 51, 32, 69, 10, 91, 45, 7,
51]

for i in range(25):
    inconsistent.append(random.randint(1,10))
print(inconsistent)
    
x = lambda a,b: a*b
x(ages, inconsistent)
```

The following is the error that I get:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-646727e92091> in <module>
     10 
     11 x = lambda a,b: a*b
---> 12 x(ages, inconsistent)

<ipython-input-24-646727e92091> in <lambda>(a, b)
      9 print(inconsistent)
     10 
---> 11 x = lambda a,b: a*b
     12 x(ages, inconsistent)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map`. Map can take `lambda` as first argument and an `iterable` as second argument.

```py
ages = [79, 91, 25, 22, 95, 69, 47, 87, 87, 2, 13, 94, 50, 73, 29, 87, 81, 51, 32, 69, 10, 91, 45, 7,
51]

print(list(map(lambda x: x * random.randint(1,10), ages)))
```

```
[553, 91, 175, 198, 285, 345, 470, 174, 87, 10, 91, 752, 50, 730, 261, 261, 567, 204, 160, 552, 90, 364, 135, 70, 51]
```

---

In your case

```py
import random

inconsistent = []
ages = [79, 91, 25, 22, 95, 69, 47, 87, 87, 2, 13, 94, 50, 73, 29, 87, 81, 51, 32, 69, 10, 91, 45, 7,
51]

for i in range(25):
    inconsistent.append(random.randint(1,10))
print(inconsistent)
    
x = lambda a,b: a*b

output = []

for i in range(25):
    output.append(x(ages[i], inconsistent[i]))
    
print(output)
```

```
[7, 7, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 10, 10, 9, 9, 7, 3, 8, 7, 5, 1, 10, 5, 2, 5, 5, 2, 9, 3]
[553, 637, 125, 110, 285, 345, 235, 870, 870, 18, 117, 658, 150, 584, 203, 435, 81, 510, 160, 138, 50, 455, 90, 63, 153]
```

Comment: The catch is that I can't use map. Have to figure out someway of accomplishing this with lambda!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
import random

ages = [79, 91, 25, 22, 95, 69, 47, 87, 87, 2, 13, 94, 50, 73, 29, 87, 81, 51, 32, 69, 10, 91, 45, 7, 51]

p = lambda x,y: x*y

[p(a, random.randint(1,10)) for a in ages]
```